# Converting annotation into a shapefile

Tags: arcgis-10.0, shapefile, error, database, annotation

I have created an annotation feature class in ArcGIS 10 and when viewed within the database, looks great. However, whenever I go into Catalog and export the annotation feature class to a shapefile, it turns the shapefile into a polygon layer. The Text is still within the attribute table, and when going into properties to set to proper fields, it does not display. I have only appended the annotation and have not feature linked them. This worked on dummy data, but now it is screwy on project data. Is there something that I am doing or a way to export annotation within a .mdb to a .shp?

Comment: the process you have described works fine for me in 10.2. Do you use 10.0? Can you outline the exact sequence of steps you are performing?

Comment: It is in 10 and not 10.2.

Comment: You can convert the polygon (with attribute name) to a line. then label the line.

Comment: I am create a new mdb, then add an annotation feature class in catalog. I then head into Map and then add in a road shp, then label and then convert to annotation. Append it to the feature class within the database. From there is converts and works fine within the database. After I make my edits, I head back into catalog and export the feature class to a shp. When I then bring in the newly exported shp, it is polygons, text is still there, but only boxes are displayed and not the text like within the mdb.

Comment: OK, do you mean you add your shapefile to a map document and it has no labels? You are supposed to label the layer in the TOC (check the TextString field in the shapefile).

Comment: When I add the annotation shapefile, it is a polygon shp and not a text shape.

Comment: I have found some other sites saying that annotation can not be housed within a shapefile. The shapefile does not support annotation. We got it to work once, but have not been able to since. Has anyone else heard about shapefiles not being able to house annotation?

Comment: Please turn these clarifications / updates into part of the question. You can easily do this using the "edit" link below the question.